# How to send a form to a API from flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, vue.js

I have this code in a vue file, in this code the data are sent to an API URL. A form is declared and the data are loaded inside it, int, string and images files, then the form is sent to the API.

```
async ArtefactoQuemadosPost(tokenGoogle) {
      this.loading = true;
      var DNIFrente = null
      var DNIDorso = null
      var factura = null
      if (this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model) === ".pdf"){
        DNIFrente = this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model
      } else {
        DNIFrente = await this.comprimirImagen(this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model, parseInt(20))
      }
      if (this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model) === ".pdf"){
        DNIDorso = this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model
      } else {
        DNIDorso = await this.comprimirImagen(this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model, parseInt(20))
      }
      if (this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model) === ".pdf"){
        factura = this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model
      } else {
        factura = await this.comprimirImagen(this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model, parseInt(20))
      }

            
      this.url =  this.$store.getters.urlBase + "/Claim/ArtefactoQuemado";

      const form = new FormData();
      form.append("Apellido", this.apellidoTitular);
      form.append("Nombre", this.nombreTitular);
      form.append("DNI", parseInt(this.dni));
      form.append("PUMc", parseFloat(this.$v.formComplete.puMc.$model));
      form.append("NumeroMedidor", parseFloat(this.$v.formComplete.numeroMedidor.$model));
      form.append("Celular",  parseFloat(this.$v.formComplete.celCompleto.$model));
      form.append("Email", this.$v.formComplete.email.$model);
      form.append("FechaDaño", this.fechacompleta);
      form.append("Descripcion", this.$v.formComplete.descripcion.$model);
      form.append("PersonalEdeseTrabajando", this.habiaPersonal);
      if (this.habiaPersonal) {
        form.append("NombrePersonalEdese", this.NombrePersonal);
        form.append("ApellidoPersonalEdese", this.ApellidoPersonal);
        form.append("FechaPersonalEdese", this.fechacompletaPersonal);
      }  

      var index = 0;
      this.artefactos.forEach(element => {
     
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][NumeroOrden]", parseInt(element.nroOrden));
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][Tipo]", element.tipo);
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][Marca]", element.marca);
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][Modelo]", element.modelo);
        form.append("ArtefactosQuemados["+index+"][NumeroSerie]", element.nroSerie);
        index++;
      });

      form.append("Files", DNIFrente, "DNI-Frente" + this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.frenteDNI.$model));
      form.append("Files", DNIDorso, "DNI-Dorso"+ this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.dorsoDNI.$model));
      form.append("Files", factura,  "Factura"+ this.extractExtFile(this.$v.formComplete.factura.$model));

      //  console.log(this.archivosConfirmados)

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
           'recaptchaToken': tokenGoogle
        },
      };

      await axios
        .post(this.url, form, config)
        .then((response) => {
          this.respuesta = response;
          this.isSaving = false;
          if (this.respuesta.status === 200) {
            this.$refs.ModalMensaje.Mensaje('Operación realizada correctamente. Nro. de tramite: ' + this.respuesta.data,'Confirmación!', '/', 'success')
     
            this.loading = false;
            //   this.$router.push("/");
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          if (e.response) {
            this.$refs.ModalMensaje.Mensaje(e.response.dat);
           
          } else {
            this.loading = false;
            this.$refs.ModalMensaje.Mensaje('Error de conexión.','Error!', '#', 'danger')
          
           
          }
         
          this.loading = false;
        });
    },
```

I want to do the same with flutter but I only get an error 400, I think it is because a I don't send the form correctly:

```
Future <String> ingresarReclamosArtefactoQuemado(

    String tokenGoogle, 
    String codLink, 
    String apellido, 
    String nombre, 
    int dni, 
    double pumc, 
    double medidor, 
    double? celular, 
    String email, 
    String fechaDano, 
    String descripcion, 
    String esPersonal, 
    String fechaHoraPersonal,
    String apellidoPersonal, 
    String nombrePersonal,
    List<List<TextEditingController>> artefactosQuemados,
    File imageFrenteDNI,
    File imageDorsoDNI,
    File imageFactura

  ) async {

    print ("Ingreso en el provider");

    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('${principalUrl}Claim/ArtefactoQuemado'));

    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    request.headers['recaptchaToken'] = tokenGoogle;

    request.fields["Apellido"] = apellido;
    request.fields["Nombre"] = nombre;
    request.fields["DNI"] = dni.toString();
    request.fields["PUMc"] = pumc.toStringAsFixed(2); // Especifica 2 decimales
    request.fields["NumeroMedidor"] = medidor.toStringAsFixed(2); // Especifica 2 decimales
    request.fields["Celular"] = celular != null ? celular.toStringAsFixed(2) : ''; // Verifica si es null antes de convertirlo
    request.fields["Email"] = email;
    request.fields["FechaDaño"] = fechaDano;
    request.fields["Descripcion"] = descripcion;
    request.fields["PersonalEdeseTrabajando"] = esPersonal;
    if (esPersonal == "SI")
    {
      request.fields["NombrePersonalEdese"] = nombrePersonal;
      request.fields["ApellidoPersonalEdese"] = apellidoPersonal;
      request.fields["FechaPersonalEdese"] = fechaHoraPersonal;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < artefactosQuemados.length; i++) {

        List<TextEditingController> innerList = artefactosQuemados[i];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < innerList.length; j++) {
        
          TextEditingController controller = innerList[j];

          if (j == 0)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][NumeroOrden]"] = (i + 1).toString();
          }
          if (j == 1)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][Tipo]"] = controller.text;
          }
          if (j == 2)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][Marca]"] = controller.text;
          }
          if (j == 3)
          { 
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][Modelo]"] = controller.text;
          }
          if (j == 4)
          {
            request.fields["ArtefactosQuemados[$i][NumeroSerie]"] = controller.text;
          }
           
          print('Elemento en posición [$i][$j]: ${controller.text}');
        
        }
    }

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFrenteDNI.path, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageDorsoDNI.path, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFactura.path, contentType: MediaType('image', 'png')));
    
    try {
      
      var response = await request.send();

      var responseBody = await response.stream.bytesToString();

      var decodedResponse;

      if (responseBody.isNotEmpty) {
        decodedResponse = json.decode(responseBody);
        // Resto del código de manejo de la respuesta
        print (decodedResponse);
      } else {
        decodedResponse = 'No hay nada en el responseBody';
      }

      return decodedResponse;

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error al enviar la solicitud: $e');
      
      return (e.toString());
    }
  }
```